# Deceiving family

Tags: family

I wanted to ask if your family continues to lies and deceive you how can the family relationship be maintained. I worry that by not talking to them is a sin. I would love to maintain the relationship but they have lied and have caused my family pain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The relationship should be maintained. Strained relationship isn't allowed even in the case of mushrik parents. If you receive harm from them, your are still obligated to exercise patience in bearing their harm and deal with them kindly, and you’ll obtain a great reward.

> The Prophet
> [ﷺ] said, ‘The Prophet said: Indeed
> Ar-Rahim (the womb) derives its root from Ar-Rahmãn (i.e., one of the
> Names of Allah) and Allah said: ‘I will keep good relation with the
> one who will keep good relation with you, (womb i.e., kith and kin)
> and sever the relation with him who will sever the relation with you,
> (womb, i.e., kith and kin).” [Reported by Bukhaari]

Comment: JazakAllah for answering my question it’s not with my parents  or siblings but other family members.

Comment: @Feb وأنتم فجزاكم الله خيرا